# Trained a model but how to predict for new instance manually?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have this script to predict wit the Gradient Boosting alg.

```
if GB_flag:
    gb_clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=20, learning_rate=0.5, max_features=2, max_depth=2, random_state=0)
    gb_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

    cross_val_score(gb_clf, x_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring="accuracy")
    y_test_pred_gb = cross_val_predict(gb_clf, x_test, y_test, cv=3)
    predictions = gb_clf.predict(x_test)
    score = gb_clf.score(x_test, y_test)
    y_test_pred = y_test_pred_gb
```

How would I now test manually a prediction of a new  array value for this model? Let's say I want to predict the outcome for an array of [12,44,0]. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.predict) function accepts array of shape (n_samples, n_features). I am guessing `n_features=3` in your case, therefore:

```
print('Your prediction for [12,44,0] is', gb_clf.predict([[12,44,0]])
```

Example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_hastie_10_2
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

X, y = make_hastie_10_2(random_state=0) # has 10 features
X_train, X_test = X[:2000], X[2000:]
y_train, y_test = y[:2000], y[2000:]

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=1.0, max_depth=1, random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
sample = [list(range(10))] # we provide 10 features for prediction
print('Prediction:', clf.predict(sample))
```